# adding commas and removing space after each class is copied cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

i am not understanding how can add commas after each class is copied i did it using for loop but it gives more different output than I want. There are around 9 div class of .name so when each one is copied i want add commas and remove extra space.

here is my code part:

```js
const A = $('.tag-container.field-name').map((i, section) => {
                    let B = $(section).find('.name')
                    return B.text()
                    })
                    .get(2)
                    console.log(A)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you want to do here.

To remove any whitespace from the left or right-hand sides of a string (eg. from `" foo "` to `"foo"`), you can use the `String.trim()` method.

Regarding the second point, I assume that in adding commas, you want to end up with a string of classnames, separated with commas, like `"foo,bar,baz"`. The `.map` method you are already using will return an array of something. You can join elements of an array together as a string with the `Array.join()` method. The `join` method takes a single argument which specifies the string to use in between each element.

Put those together, and you end up with something like:

```js
const A = $(".tag-container.field-name")
  .map((i, section) => {
    let B = $(section).find(".name");
    return B.text().trim(); // Note use of trim
  })
  .join(',') // Join all elements of the array with the `,` character

console.log(A);
// Something like `"foo,bar,baz"`
```

Comment: getting an error on log:
TypeError: $(...).map(...).join is not a function

Comment: well i did something different and got the output( used arrays)

Comment: Could you please edit your comments to include what the error is, and what steps you needed to take to resolve it? That way anyone looking at this in future will be able to learn also

Answer (score 1):

Use trim and join:

```
$(css).get().map(el => $(el).text().trim()).join(', ')
```